# JMapViewer ADD tiles for offline view

Tags: java, swing, openstreetmap, offline-mode

Hello I'm using this sample in Java to try to load OpenStreetMaps Offline tiles,

for example I have my tiles on C:/OSM/tiles/

but I need to know how to add this information in map (JMapViewer) class to load tiles locally.

Thank you very much for your help this is my source:

```
//License: GPL. Copyright 2008 by Jan Peter Stotz

import org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.JMapViewer;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 *
 * Demonstrates the usage of {@link JMapViewer}
 *
 * @author Jan Peter Stotz
 *
 */
public class Demo extends JFrame {

    public Demo() {
        super("JMapViewer Demo");
        setSize(400, 400);
        final JMapViewer map = new JMapViewer();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        final JCheckBox showMapMarker = new JCheckBox("Map markers visible");
        showMapMarker.setSelected(map.getMapMarkersVisible());
        showMapMarker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                map.setMapMarkerVisible(showMapMarker.isSelected());
            }
        });
        panel.add(showMapMarker);
        final JCheckBox showTileGrid = new JCheckBox("Tile grid visible");
        showTileGrid.setSelected(map.isTileGridVisible());
        showTileGrid.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                map.setTileGridVisible(showTileGrid.isSelected());
            }
        });
        panel.add(showTileGrid);
        final JCheckBox showZoomControls = new JCheckBox("Show zoom controls");
        showZoomControls.setSelected(map.getZoomContolsVisible());
        showZoomControls.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                map.setZoomContolsVisible(showZoomControls.isSelected());
            }
        });
        panel.add(showZoomControls);
        add(map, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //
//      map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(49.814284999, 8.642065999));
//      map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(49.91, 8.24));
//      map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(49.71, 8.64));
//      map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(48.71, -1));
//      map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(49.807, 8.644));

        map.setDisplayPositionByLatLon(-0.223056, -78.5126, 11);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compile by the source directly and change

> \org\openstreetmap\gui\jmapviewer\tilesources\AbstractOsmTileSource.java

Here is the source code inside JMapViewer.zip/JMapViewer_src.jar extract the Jar file and copy the folder /org in the mail source code folder

http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/releases/2011-02-19/JMapViewer.zip

and change the next

```
 public AbstractOsmTileSource(String name, String base_url, String attr_img_url) {
        this.name = name;
     // this.baseUrl = base_url;
        this.baseUrl = "file:///C:/OSM/tiles";
        attrImgUrl = attr_img_url;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A much better alternative that doesn't require modifying JMapViewer and recompiling it is to provide your own TileSource implementation, as shown [here](http://paulusschoutsen.nl/blog/2012/08/java-component-jmapviewer-with-offline-openstreetmap-support/).

Grab the [OfflineOsmTileSource](https://github.com/balloob/JMapViewer/blob/master/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/tilesources/OfflineOsmTileSource.java), and use it like the blog post says.

Simple and elegant. All you need is some osm tiles stored locally, which I assume you already have.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember JMapViewer is designed to work only using online maps.

Changing that behavior seams to be complicated. May be you can achieve this by implementing your own `org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.TileLoader` instance. The implementation only has to be able to create Runnable instances that load a specific tile into the TileCache and inform the registered TileLoaderListener that a tile loading is completed.

Comment: I do it in debugger, now I need do it in source code

`// Change 

JMapViewer.tileController.tileSource.baseUrl = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org"
JMapViewer.tileSource.baseUrl = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org"

//to

JMapViewer.tileController.tileSource.baseUrl = "file:///C:/OSM/tiles"
JMapViewer.tileSource.baseUrl = "file:///C:/OSM/tiles"`

Comment: I need recompile JMapViewer.jar changing this values

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this approach wasn't supported back when this thread happened, but for caching offline tiles they provide OsmFileCacheTileLoader;

http://josm.openstreetmap.de/doc/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/OsmFileCacheTileLoader.html

It is super easy to use.

```
this.mapViewer = new JMapViewer();
OsmFileCacheTileLoader ofctl;
try {
    File cacheDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "OpenStreetMapTileCache");
    logger.info("Home Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.home") + ", cacheDir=" + cacheDir);
    cacheDir.mkdirs();
    ofctl = new OsmFileCacheTileLoader(mapViewer, cacheDir);
    this.mapViewer.setTileLoader(ofctl);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MapDisplayPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception creating OsmFileCacheTileLoader" + ex, ex);
}
```