# Zoom in and out on jLayeredPane on multiple JPanel

Tags: jpanel, jlayeredpane

I am presently using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636369/jlayeredpane-background-image-icon-layer/37456381#37456381) but wasnt able to get the zoom in and out. Can someone please help me.

What I want is on mouse event zoom in and out both `background Layer + Compass Layer`

Comment: It is better to ask specific questions - "isn't working" doesn't really provide a lot of information. Please consider taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help for information on how to improve your question.

Comment: Which code? The code in [answe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14636750/3603374)r or the code in [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636369/jlayeredpane-background-image-icon-layer)?