# JMapViewer Routing between coordinates

Tags: java, google-maps, routes, openstreetmap, jmapviewer

Is it possible to display a route between two coordinates on JMapViewer on a Java application?
I have managed to draw a polygon and get a straight line between two coordinates however I was wondering what would be required to actually make the line appear on the road?
The map being used in JMapViewer is open street map.

Thanks

Comment: You may find [Draw Polyline in JMapViewer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20252592/1048330) useful.