# JMapViewer draw a polygon that will look like arrow

Tags: java, google-maps, jmapviewer

I want to create an arrow (---->) on my map, connecting 2 given coordinates.

By now I used the draw line using polygon implementation suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252592/draw-polyline-in-jmapviewer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744798/draw-line-between-two-geo-points-in-jmapviewer)

Is there a way to acheieve it?

Thanks,
Ozrad

Comment: Generally yes, you could use the concepts demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607427/java-make-a-directed-line-and-make-it-move/15607737#15607737) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129281/mouse-motion-listener-only-in-one-direction/20131064#20131064) for some ideas.  These both use `Path2D` to generate the shape and calculate the angle between points to orientate the shape.  Your requirement is actually a little easier, as you will already have a start and end point, so it should be possible to either calculate the length of the line or angle of the arrow

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need the arrow to be in JMapViewer and your links show it in Graphics2D I think?

Comment: And so are yours.  Your first link creates `Path2D` and paints it to `Graphics2D` context...

Comment: OK I see what you mean, Thanks! You can write it as an answer and i'll mark it if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally yes, you could use the concepts demonstrated in [Java make a directed line and make it move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607427/java-make-a-directed-line-and-make-it-move/15607737#15607737) and [mouse motion listener only in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129281/mouse-motion-listener-only-in-one-direction/20131064#20131064) for some ideas.

These both use Path2D to generate the shape and calculate the angle between two points to orientate the shape.

Your requirement is actually a little easier, as you will already have a start and end point, so it should be possible to either calculate the length of the line or angle of the arrow head, depending on which is simpler for you (I'd be calculating the length of the line between the points and rotating it, but that's just me)

Comment: I envy you with the chance to play around with `JMapViewer` ;)

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution, based on @MadProgrammer help, is this:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.MapPolygonImpl;
import org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces.ICoordinate;

public class MyMapMarkerArrow extends MapPolygonImpl {

    public MyMapMarkerArrow(List<? extends ICoordinate> points) {
        super(null, null, points);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, List<Point> points) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(getColor());
        g2d.setStroke(getStroke());
        Path2D path = buildPath(points);
        g2d.draw(path);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private Path2D buildPath(List<Point> points) {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        if (points != null && points.size() > 0) {
            Point firstPoint = points.get(0);
            path.moveTo(firstPoint.getX(), firstPoint.getY());
            for (Point p : points) {
                path.lineTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
            }

            int pointsSize = points.size() - 1;

            if (points.get(0).getY() > points.get(1).getY()) {
                path.lineTo(points.get(pointsSize).getX(),
                        points.get(pointsSize).getY() + 20);

                path.moveTo(points.get(pointsSize).getX(),
                        points.get(pointsSize).getY());

                path.lineTo(points.get(pointsSize).getX() - 20,
                        points.get(pointsSize).getY());
            } else {
                path.lineTo(points.get(pointsSize).getX(),
                        points.get(pointsSize).getY() - 20);

                path.moveTo(points.get(pointsSize).getX(),
                        points.get(pointsSize).getY());

                path.lineTo(points.get(pointsSize).getX() + 20,
                        points.get(pointsSize).getY());
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Thanks again for the help