# How I can put an image like an arrow between two points in JMapViewer

Tags: java, jmap, jmapviewer

How I can put an image that goes from point `p1` to point `p2`? Anyone can suggest a way to me?

Edit: I follow this example, [*Draw Line between two Geo Points in JMapViewer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744798/draw-line-between-two-geo-points-in-jmapviewer/10747783#10747783), to draw a path between two `geoPoints`. But when I try to delete a `MapPolygon`, that I created first, it's not work and I don't know why. The input is correct, trust me!

```
List<Coordinate> route = new ArrayList<Coordinate>(Arrays.asList(one, two, two));
        List<MapPolygon> lista=cartina.getMapPolygonList();
        MapPolygon arrow=new MapPolygonImpl(route);
        cartina.removeMapPolygon(arrow);
```

Edit: I do this:

```
private Coordinate one;
private Coordinate two;
public ExampleClass(Coordinate one, Coordinate two) {
    this.one=one;
    this.two=two;
}

public method (){ //click button
    List<Coordinate> route = new ArrayList<Coordinate>(Arrays.asList(one, two, two));
    map.addMapPolygon(new MapPolygonImpl(route));
}

public methodB(){// click anothe button
 List<Coordinate> route = new ArrayList<Coordinate>(Arrays.asList(one, two, two));
    map.removeMapPolygon()(new MapPolygonImpl(route));
}
```

Comment: You can draw an arrow shaped polygon, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10747783/230513).

Comment: @trashgod thanks for your link it works correct. But I have another question. IF I add a MapPolygon in MapPolygon list and after I would delete a MapPolygon and I use the algorithm that you linked me and I create another LinkedList etc... the JMapViewer don't delete the MapPolygon... do you know why? How i can delete a MapPolygon after that I add in MapPolygonList

Comment: Good question; I've elaborated [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26554830/230513); please update your question to reflect your addition concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can put an [arrow] that goes from point `p1` to point `p2`?

As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747783/230513), you can add an arrow shaped `MapPolygon` to your `JMapViewer` using `addMapPolygon()`.

> After I delete a `MapPolygon`…and I create another `LinkedList`…the `JMapViewer` doesn't delete the `MapPolygon`. Do you know why?

Use the complementary method `removeMapPolygon()` to remove a `MapPolygon`, but be sure that it's a reference to the *same* `MapPolygon` that you added and *not* a reference to a `LinkedList` you might have used while creating the arrow. Use `removeAllMapPolygons()` to completely `clear()` the map viewer's internal list of polygons.

Addendum: Here's a concrete example illustrating `addMapPolygon()` and `removeMapPolygon()`.

```
List<Coordinate> route = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(one, two, three));
final MapPolygonImpl mapPolygon = new MapPolygonImpl(route);
map.addMapPolygon(mapPolygon);
toolBar.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Remove") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        map.removeMapPolygon(mapPolygon);
    }
}));
```

Comment: I think that it's better post the question:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552250/dont-delete-mappolygon-in-jmapviewer?noredirect=1#comment41731447_26552250 if you look in this link I use removeMalPolygon() but it doesn't work!! the two points that I use are the same trust me!

Comment: now I urdestand!! if I use this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552250/dont-delete-mappolygon-in-jmapviewer?noredirect=1#comment41731447_26552250 it's doesn't work because it's not the same reference??

Comment: I'm not sure form your fragment; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).